# How to forward a domain to a Wamp Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, domain-name

I have not been able to find a guide that resolves my issues with forwarding my domain to my wamp apache server.

I've portforwarded correctly and I've made my webpage accessible through my ipv6.

So far I've tried putting every combination of example.com and www.example.com for `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` in httpd-vhosts.conf.
I've also made these dns records in my domain.

```
A       host   points to
        @      my.ipv6

CNAME   host   points to
        www    @
```

I'm obviously missing something because it's not working.

Also, if I wanted to forward a subdomain to apache would I just change `@` to `subdir.example.com` in the dns records?

Comment: Did you try to ping your domain name from command prompt or terminal to check if it is returning the right IP?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was doing it right and it just took the domain a long time to update. It's working now but I don't know why it wasn't for the past two days.

Should I delete this post considering the nature of it?